# A name for matrices with only simple eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am constantly working with hermitian matrices without multiplicity in their spectrum. Since this hypothesis appear in several important problems, for instance perturbation theory, I looked in the literature for an accepted terminology but found nothing. Does anyone know a reference where these matrices, or their set, have been given a name ? I am considering calling them "simple matrices" but it is a bit ambiguous...

Comment: I don't know of any established terminology but surely `simple' is a candidate for the most over-used adjective in mathematics. Anything else would be better!!

Comment: @NickGill: Anything?  Let's try out http://www.randomlists.com/random-adjectives to test that.  "Paltry matrices" or "upbeat matrices", perhaps?

Comment: «Multiplicity-free» is a good name.

Comment: Another suggestion is *separable*, because the characteristic polynomial is separable.

Comment: To me a simple matrix is one whose characteristic polynomial is irreducible.

Comment: What about "generic"? Is it too generic?

Comment: @PeterMueller: I like this suggestion, also because it is a single word as opposed to two words like "regular semisimple" or "multiplicity free" or "beatup (sic.) matrices" :-)

Comment: @suv...rit: since in this case the matrices are already Hermitian, they are automatically semisimple so you can simply say "regular".

Comment: Thank you all for the very good suggestions. It appears however that these matrices already have a name (in fact two, depending on the context), so my question has been answered.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since your matrices are Hermitian, this is the same as *non-derogatory* ... see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_matrices for terminology *derogatory matrix*.

Answer (score 22):

In the context of algebraic groups, these are the regular semisimple elements of $GL_n$. The "semisimple" part means diagonalizable, and the "regular" part means that the centralizer has dimension $n$. So you could call them regular semisimple.

Comment: I like this answer, but a quick search on google showed that "non derogatory" is a much more common name in linear algebra (altough I never heard of it before). So I accepted Gerald's answer.

Comment: Sure ! I gave you the terminology that people who work with algebraic groups use, but you should choose the one that will sound familiar to the people who read you !

Answer (score 6):

Apparently, there is something I don't understand in this discussion. Why should one reinvent the wheel? Such matrices have always been known as **Hermitian matrices with simple spectrum**. Just look at [this wiktionary entry](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Hermitian_matrix) or [Terry Tao's blog](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/12/254a-notes-3a-eigenvalues-and-sums-of-hermitian-matrices/) out of [thousands of other examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=hermitian%20matrix%20%22simple%20spectrum%22&rlz=1C1TSCD_enCA534CA534&oq=hermitian%20matrix%20%22simple%20spectrum%22&aqs=chrome.0.69i59.5332j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Answer (score 1):

Since "almost all" (in the Lebesgue sense) matrices have multiplicity-free spectrum, you can use something like "general position" or "generic".

Alternatively, "multiplicity-free spectrum matrix" or "MFSM" could also work.